# Prevent text entry in a number formatted column

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you stop users entering text in a number cell or column. I have users that insist on writing 3+2 instead of 5. How do you stop this?

Please don't ask me why they do this. It is a tradition that goes way back

Answer (score 1):

Use Data Validation.

Select the cell that you want to control. Then in the Data tab select Data Validation.

Then in the Allow, select Custom and put the formula:

```
=ISNUMBER(A1)
```

Where `A1` is the cell in which you are putting the Data Validation.

[image]

Now when they try to put `2+3` they will get an error.

[image]

And will have to change it to a number for it to be accepted.

Comment: Thank you. That is simple and answers the question perfectly. Is there a a way to just highlight cells where the entry does not conform to number format. It has only just occurred to me that some data may be pasted in. We don't want to refuse the data but would need to notify the user that it's format is cinorrect?

Comment: you can use the same type of formula in a conditional format rule that will highlight when it is not a number.  But that is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Data Validation still has a couple potential flaws for you. Probably will not bother you in this case, but things to note:

1. They can still enter a formula so long as it results in a number. So `=3+2` is a valid entry. Why would it not be an issue? Because the displayed result looks like a directly type "5" so maybe "who cares" applies. But if having a "constant" (Excel term) in the cell, never odd things like formulas, is important to work depending on the cell entries, you still have a problem.
2. They can still paste over the cell, wiping out any data validation and so its enforcement will be non-existent. If "tradition" means they are #*$$%&#'s that don't follow rules, you'll have troubles since they will seek ways to defeat you, count on it. This is war, act accordingly. If "tradition" means they have actual reason for such entries, then consider what those reasons might be. For instance, if they have data coming in an unorganized way, learning "3" should be entered there, then later, that another "2" needs added in, they might've entered the "3" when encountering it and feel appending "+2" a more accurate way of noting the "2" they learn about later. After all, let the computers do the arithmetic for no mistakes whereas doing it themselves leads to silly mistakes, but also to wondering "Did I add in that 2 from later? Or... I guess I didn't, let's add it in now." And if it dates far enough back, it could be from paper and pencil days when that is EXACTLY what any right-thinking person would have done. In that case, there are two thoughts:

   a. You should give them an entry area where they can do what their work process requires. This is not them against you, it's providing for user needs. Then put formulas in this place that total those up. (For the exact example, use Excel's Version 4 Macro command `EVALUATE()` but IN a Named Range name, as its "Refers to". Not helpful though, if entries like "3, 2" also exist.)

   b. Bear in mind that if it were important to MY work process, I'd add a sheet and do as I pleased, then copy the column of entries ONTO your data area in whatever form I worked with them. Well, honestly, I'd do the work of converting them to simple numbers, then plop those in as I'm not one of the #*$$%&#'s I referred to earlier. But not everyone would, and not everyone can. That might cover plenty of people so...

I suspect "tradition" means the bit in which the work process needs this kind of entry. So think about solving that, perhaps.

To beat them all, except those who know how to launch a file without macros working, VBA is your solution of choice. It can fire macros when someone presses the Enter key, or clicks elsewhere after editing the cell of choice. Those could enforce your need and perhaps very effectively, by asking a question they have to respond to such as "Your entry was '3+2'. Does that mean a total of 5 or does it have some other meaning?" A couple years replying to those endless questions might do the trick for even the most curmudgeonly. Follow-up questions should be available too, like "Oh, then what does it mean?", "Um, I don't get it. What does 'No, you fool, "it means 3+2!"' mean then?" "I do not understand. What does '3,2,7' mean?" and so on.

But think VBA if "tradition" means more "I do what I want!" (thank you Cartman) and not "Um, I HAVE to enter things this way for good reasons."